# JavaFX - Set Style of TableView's Header

Tags: javafx, view, styles

I am trying to modify the style for the column header of a Table View in JavaFX. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
table.lookup(".column-header-background").lookup(".filler").setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
table.lookup(".column-header").setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
```

And this is what it creates: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoh9a.png)

However, I would like the entire header to be colored - product, unit price, discount, total.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: lookupAll for the headers

Comment: This would be easier with an external style sheet. Is there a reason to keep using inline CSS?